# Pandas moving average calculation missing dates?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple moving average using the live forex data from `Alpha Vantage` (API key can be registered for free from Alpha Vantage). Everything seems to work fine except that the period for the SMA is not complete.

For example, if I set `data[:'2020-1-1']`, it should return data from 1.1.2020 up to current date. However, what happens is that the the period from December 2020 to January 2021 is gone.

I tried plotting the graph and realize that the larger my moving average period is, the more recent data are being removed. The plot on my graph is as follows:

[GBP USD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHAWD.jpg)

[Dataframe for beginning period 2020-1-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBBly.jpg)

[Dataframe period fixed but NAN values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0nHR.jpg)

Below are my codes in 3 separate files:

This is the execution.py file:

```py
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from to_USD import currencyExchangeB
from smvgavg import sma

UniSymbol = 'USD'
fromSymbolsB = ['EUR','GBP']

for symbol in fromSymbolsB:
    # store the result that return from "currencyExchange()" function
    result = currencyExchangeB(UniSymbol,symbol)

    # generate graph by passing those result of each currency data
    sma(result,UniSymbol,symbol)
```

The next one is the to_USD.py file where I use it to pull the foreign currency data from Alpha Vantage:

```py
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# added a class to collect a collection of variable so it can be return easily in the following function
class GRAPH_STRUCT:
    date:any
    symbol:str
    def __init__(self,date,symbol):
        self.date = date
        self.symbol = symbol

def currencyExchangeB(toCurrencyB,fromCurrencyB):
    # create an array to store the result
    result = []

    cc = ForeignExchange(key='%ALPHA_VANTAGE_APIKEY%',output_format='pandas')
    data, meta_data = cc.get_currency_exchange_daily(from_symbol=fromCurrencyB,to_symbol=toCurrencyB,outputsize='full')

    # append those result in the array
    result = GRAPH_STRUCT(data[:'2020-1-1'],toCurrencyB)

    # return those result in the end of the function
    return result
```

The last file is the smvgavg.py file used to calculate the simple moving average:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#dataObj is a datatype of GRAPH_STRUCT
def sma(dataObj,UniSymbol,symbol):
    maA = 25
    maB = 50
    maT = [maA,maB]
    for ma in maT:
        smaString = "SMA" + str(ma)

        data = dataObj.date
        data[smaString] = data.iloc[:,3].rolling(window = ma).mean()
        data = data.iloc[ma:]

        print(data)
        fig = plt.gcf()
        fig.set_size_inches(10, 6)
        plt.plot(data['4. close'], label='Close' if ma == 0 else "",color='red')
        plt.plot(data['SMA' + str(ma)],label='SMA' + str(ma))

    plt.title(symbol + '/' + UniSymbol, y=1)
    plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel("Exchange Rate")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: you can make use of the `min_periods=1` parameter , `Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value. min_periods will default to the size of the window`. refer [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't because of `pandas` or Python, rather, it's because of how the SMA is calculated. Unless you do the computation yourself just to see what's going on, it can be kind of tricky.

The formula for the simple moving average is to take *n* amount of closing prices at *n* interval. And divide by *n*. Where *P* is the closing price and the number is an even interval in your *n*-day SMA, one period of a 5-day SMA would look something like this:

```
(P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 + P5)/5
```

The reason some of your starting dates appear to be missing is because the data point calculated from a period is placed at the **end** of that period. For example, let's have a look at `Airbnb (ABNB)` on TD Ameritrade's *thinkorswim*. This stock was just recently listed, so we can easily see that this 50-day SMA (purple line) *also* has some dates that appear to be missing:
[image]

What you *can* do is get earlier information that you are not going to display in your graph.

For example, if you want to display 10-day SMA line for the dates December 2020 to February 2021, you could factor in the data **10 days before** your start date, and then just graph your start date to the end date. This would fill in that area that appears to be missing because your calculations now account for the previous period (that won't be graphed).

Comment: May I know how can I factor in the date 10 days before start date using python?

Comment: You are going to have to factor that into your API request or your selection of data points from the data returned by the request. For example, graph: `data['2020-11-20':'data[2021-1-1]']` (if you want to graph December 2020 to January 2021, because now you're accounting for the 10 days before your start date)

Comment: Hello gmdev. I just noticed the example of the graph you showed me has missing data at the starting point. However, the missing data in my chart are reversed. The more recent data are the ones actually gone. I have updated my question to show you what is happening. I have uploaded the image named GBP USD just before the first set of code in my question.

Comment: It seems that the data are not plotted at the end of the period. I am trying to plot the moving average up to the most recent day.

Comment: Hello gmdev. I have updated the question. The dataframe is just below the GBP USD image. I have maintained the codes as per the question without editing anything.

Comment: Your data for the second dataframe seems to just stop at the point `2020-11-25`. This is reflected on the graph. What is this line for: `data = data.iloc[ma:]`? This seems like it's going to cut off `25` days and `50` days for each moving average.

Comment: I tried removing the `data = data.iloc[ma:]` . My dataframe now includes the most recent dates. However, the recent dates have NAN values. It is as shown at the question below the GBP USD image.

Comment: Then I tried inserting the `min_periods=1` as suggested by @Shijith. Now it works fine. Thanks a lot @gmdev and @Shijith for all the trouble.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out, definitely an interesting problem! Also, thanks to @Shijith for the input :)